# how to achieve more output about hidden processes?

Tags: command-line

unhide has found hidden processes on my machine with given PID.
These PID are not listed in top or in htop.

how can I get more output of these hidden processes, when PID is given ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a command line tool for displaying information about running processes, try:

```
ps --pid=PID
```

If you want more information

```
ps ux --pid=PID
```

... will provide more information about the process.

If the hidden processes are indicative of some kind of intrusion you may need to ensure you have clean ps/top that are not hiding bad processes.